# Workaround for Href tag in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am using dojo for scripting.
I want to give the href tag which link to the local path of an excel file.
It works fine in IE ie., when I click on the link it asks for open/save/cancel.
But the same code isn't working for Firefox.
Is there any workaround for that?
I am writing the code, I look forward to your useful comments.

```
var href = dojo.place ('<"a href = /path/abc.csv"><Export></a>',dojo.body());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your quotes in the wrong place:

```
var href = dojo.place ('<a href = "/path/abc.csv"><Export></a>',dojo.body());
// Not here -------------^        ^
// Yes here ----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML syntax is invalid - it should be `<a href="/path/abc.csv">Export</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the place of the quote. It should be after href

```
var href = dojo.place ('<a href = "/path/abc.csv">',dojo.body());
```

Comment: Yaa I have corrected my corrected my code..but still it is not showing the open/save/close box.. Rather than it showing the content of  my excel  file...

Answer (score 0):

You are placed double quoate at anchor tag, it is wrong,

```
var href = dojo.place ('<"a href = /path/abc.csv"><Export></a>',dojo.body());
```

Your anchor tag href should be change as

```
var href = dojo.place ('<a href = "/path/abc.csv"><Export></a>',dojo.body());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes `" ... "` are not at correct place and syntax is not valid. it should be:

```
var href = dojo.place ('<a href = "/path/abc.csv"><Export></a>',dojo.body());
                                  ^
//note quotes here................^
```